# Get color functions work for windows 7, Do not work for windows ten. Is there a solution?

Tags: c++

Here is a simple return red rgb color funcion:

```
int getRed(int x, int y){
COLORREF color;
HDC hDC;
hDC = GetDC(NULL);
color = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);

int red = static_cast<int>(GetRValue(color));

std::cout << "Red - " << red << "  \n";

ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);
return red;
}
```

This function works perfectly along with the other two that return blue and green on windows 7. However when i try to run this program on windows 10, it does not work at all, it almost always gives a 0 or 255 value, if it does give an inbetween value its not even close to the actual color being checked. Does anyone know how to get this code running on windows 10?

Comment: yes,instead of giving a range, lets say if i was color checking a color with an r value of 87, this function would return either a 0 or a 255 , but only on windows 10, works perfectly on windows 7.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me in Windows 10 using 0,0 as the coordinates. My desktop background is 45,125,154 and I get 45 as the red color.  Perhaps your screen coordinates have changed in Windows 10? You should be checking if the COLORREF is CLR_INVALID to detect an error. `The return value is the COLORREF value that specifies the RGB of the pixel. If the pixel is outside of the current clipping region, the return value is CLR_INVALID (0xFFFFFFFF defined in Wingdi.h).`

Comment: The screen coordinates are the same, i checked it using SetPhysicalCursorPos(x,y) to the same coordinates i was pixel checking. The program is exactly the same on both machines, i just reinstalled it.

Comment: Are you getting back the invalid color value? Is there something you're not telling us, like it's a full-screen game or something using DirectX or OpenGL that might not work the same way in newer versions of Windows?

Comment: Try this: http://rextester.com/YZC19583 It gives me the correct colors for the top left pixel of both of my monitors.

Comment: I just created a new project, put in this color checking code and only this code, It will not return the correct rgb values for this machine, this is blowing my mind. I tried what you suggested and thank you very much but it didnt help, i am not getting invalid color back. I also ran this code on my wifes computer (windows 7) works perfectly, so maybe there is an issue with my laptop, windows 10, and this program.

Comment: Is maybe the problem ReleaseDC(desktopWindow,dc); my windows 10 is a laptop, not sure if that should matter. Thank you so much for your help. but even your code wont run on this machine. Works fine on my other machines.

Comment: The code gives weird results on my machine. The result depends on the background color but e.g. white background is reported as color value 5a5126 (hex). Most probably the Desktop Window Manager is involved here.